# rspec-api-documentation gem shows `[binary data]` instead of the response body

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec-api-documentation

While using the [rspec-api-documentation](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation) gem in markdown mode (`config.format = [:markdown]`) I noticed that the documentation generated is lacking the response body.

Is there a permanent fix for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The problem is documented in [this issue](https://github.com/zipmark/rspec_api_documentation/issues/456) and there does not seem to be a permanent fix at the moment. A workaround has been posted in the issues comment and it involves monkey-patching:

```
module RspecApiDocumentation
  class RackTestClient < ClientBase
    def response_body
      last_response.body.encode("utf-8")
    end
  end
end
```

Adding the code in the initializer (`rspec_api_docs.rb`) before generating the documentation seems to solve the issue.